# Jquery how to synchronise toggle button symbol change when opening and closing different divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

The code below has four different divs, they open and close when the down arrow and x symbols are clicked. When the dropdown arrow is clicked the div opens to show a list and the dropdown arrows changes to a X close symbol. When X button is clicked the div closes. This part works fine. Also, if one div is open and a another div is clicked the first div will close and the new div will open, which also works, however the previous X button does not revert to a down arrow.  So, the switch between button symbols only happens correctly when X symbol is used to close a div. I would like the X close button to revert back to a down arrow button if another div is clicked on. [Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atataylor/wfendkrp/2/)

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        .dropdown{
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
            background: #979292;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 15px 15px;
        }
        .dropdown-container{
            
            display: none;
        }
        .btn{
        float: right;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
            
        }
        
        .btn:before{
    content: "\25BC";
    cursor: pointer;
        
        }
    .btn.switch:before{
     content: "\2715";
     cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
<div  class="dropdown">
    Dropdown List 1
  <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List a</li>
      <li>List b</li>
      <li>List c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown ">Dropdown List 2
 <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List d</li>
      <li>List e</li>
      <li>List f</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div  class="dropdown ">
    Dropdown List 3
 <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List g</li>
      <li>List h</li>
      <li>List i</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="dropdown">My Dropdown 4
        <button class="openClose btn"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
      <li>Item a</li>
      <li>Item b</li>
      <li>Item c</li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $(".openClose", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    });

});
    
  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });
     $('.btn').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('switch');
            });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you have to do is when clicking a "openClose" btn, find all other "openClose" btn under the divs which is not current "div" and toggle the "switch" class;

Same with click outside, "html", remove all btn if they have class "switch".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('div.dropdown').each(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  $(".openClose", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
    $div.toggle();
    $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    var notClicked =  $('div.dropdown').not($(this).parent());      
    notClicked.find(".switch").toggleClass('switch');
    return false;
  });
});
    
  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
    $(".btn").removeClass("switch")
  });
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("switch");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown{
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background: #979292;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}
.dropdown-container{
  display: none;
}
.btn{
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;   
}
.btn::before{
    content: "\25BC";
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn.switch::before{
  content: "\2715";
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="dropdown">
    Dropdown List 1
  <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List a</li>
      <li>List b</li>
      <li>List c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown ">Dropdown List 2
 <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List d</li>
      <li>List e</li>
      <li>List f</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div  class="dropdown ">
    Dropdown List 3
 <button class="openClose btn"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" >
    <ul>
      <li>List g</li>
      <li>List h</li>
      <li>List i</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="dropdown">My Dropdown 4
        <button class="openClose btn"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
      <li>Item a</li>
      <li>Item b</li>
      <li>Item c</li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ StevenXXCCC
Thanks Stevenfor your help, almost there, however the last click to close the div when not selecting any more divs closes the div but leaves the X button rather than the down arrow. But thanks for your help I will keep on working on it. Cheers

Comment: I don't see the issue you have, could you try refresh the page and re-run the snippet to test?

Comment: @ StevenXXCCC. Thanks Steven its working fine now must have been my browser, thanks again for your help. Jezza

Comment: No problem mate, glad my answer helped!